# ¿Cómo usar adecuadamente el "Try" y el "Catch" al emplear el "Scanner"?

Tags: java, try-catch, java-util-scanner, joptionpane

He estado realizando un programa en JAVA en la cual solicito un valor entero a través de la consola. Mi problema es que hago uso de los bloques "TRY" y "CATCH" para evitar una posible excepción en la entrada de valores que no sean enteros, y al entrar al bloque "CATCH" le digo al usuario el motivo de la excepción y le pido que digite un valor que sea entero, pero el programa no me lo permite y la verdad no sé el motivo.
Cuando realizo el mismo programa pero con el "JOptionPane", sí me es posible introducir otro valor. No sé si sea cosa de la clase Scanner o algo que mis limitados conocimientos de programación aún desconozcan.

```java
// Bloque TRY
try {
    
    // Ciclo WHILE para los números positivos
    while (n>=0) {
        System.out.print("Introduce el valor "+i+":"); 
        n=entrada.nextInt();
        
        // Condicional IF para números positivos
        if(n>=0) {
            System.out.println(i+".- "+n);
            i++;
        // Números negativos
        } else {
            System.out.println("--El valor es negativo--");
        }
        
    }

// Bloque  CATCH para evitar datos que no sean valores enteros
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("--INTRODUCE UN NÚMERO ENTERO--"); 
    System.out.println(e.getClass().getSimpleName());
    e.printStackTrace(); 
    
    while(n>=0) {
        System.out.print("Introduce el valor "+i+": ");
        n=entrada.nextInt();
        
        // Condicional IF para números positivos
        if(n>=0) {
            System.out.println(i+".- "+n);
            i++;
            
        // Números negativos
        } else {
            System.out.println("--EL VALOR ES NEGATIVO--"); 
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. EL código, los errores y demás datos de la pregunta van como texto siempre (a menos que necesitemos ver algo de interfaz). La gente es mejor compilando en sus terminales que en la mente ;) Recuerda que puedes [edit] la pregunta todo lo que haga falta para complementarla o mejorarla

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al ingresar un dato no numérico,debes limpiar el valor almacenado en el Buffer de la clase Scanner,el cual es una parte de la memoria reservada para almacenar datos que povienen desde los perifericos de entrada como por ejemplo un teclado,Esto quiere decir que los datos que se teclean hacen el siguiente recorrido:

> 1 Se escribe un dato y al pulsar ENTER,este se envia a la memoria del ordenador

> 2 Un buffer,recibe los datos del usuario.EL buffer recibirá por un lado el dato enviado y por otro lado la pulsacion ENTER en un codigo Ascii

> 3 Una vez que el buffer recibe el dato lo pasa a la variable correspondiente

en resumen..el buffer al ingresar un valor esta guardando por un lado ese valor y por otro un `\n` al dar enter, el cual es considerado un valor de tipo `String` en java.. Si ingreso un dato no numerico,ejemplo escribo hola al dar enter el buffer guardara hola\n

solución:
una manera común de limpiar el buffer es aplicando el metodo nexLine().ala instancia de la clase Scanner en tu caso

```
 catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("--INTRODUCE UN NÚMERO ENTERO--"); 
    System.out.println(e.getClass().getSimpleName());
    e.printStackTrace(); 
    entrada.nextLine();//limpiando el buffer con el dato no numerico guardado
```

ten en cuenta que esto aplicaría solo una vez por  que la exception solo se activa al primer valor no numérico que ingresas, por lo que mi recomendación seria que aplicaras un do while que encierre el TRY-CATCH  para que la exception siga repitiéndose en caso se ingrese un dato no numerico otra vez

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias por tu ayuda, la verdad me ayudaste mucho en aclarar cada una de mis dudas, enserio que te lo agradezco. Perdón por no haber respondido antes pero por motivos personales no había podido hacer uso de mis redes y dispositivos. No sé muy bien como funciona este foro pero quiero que sepas que te agradezco mucho ;)